# Why aren't my files showing? Using Amazon S3 with ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, amazon-s3, coldfusion-10

I have the following code to put a file on to an Amazon S3 bucket and then retrieve the directory listing:

```
<!--- set a variable to hold our S3 directory --->
<cfset s3Dir = "s3://#access_ID#:#secret_key#@bucket/folder/">

<!--- check if directory exists and create if not --->
<cfif not directoryExists(s3Dir)>
  <cfset directoryCreate(s3Dir)>
</cfif>

<!--- create a random file with a random number as its content --->
<cfset fileWrite
('#s3Dir#/RandomFile_#DateFormat(Now(),'yyyymmdd')#-#TimeFormat(Now(),'HHmmss')#.txt',
 '#RandRange(100000,100000000)#')>

<!--- get the directory contents --->
<cfdump var="#directoryList(s3Dir)#">
```

The file saves to Amazon S3 correctly and I can see it using the S3 console. But the dumped out directory contents is always an empty array. Any ideas as to why this might be?

Comment: I have checked for same code in ColdFusion 9 and seems working fine and displaying array of files. But yes, same code return empty array in ColdFusion 10. May be bug in CF10.
EDIT: RAILO work fine as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have just found the answer on Adobe's bug base at https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3554224

It is caused by having a trailing slash at the end of the directory path. Once I remove the trailing slash and restarted CF the file names are returned as expected.